# Angular is throwing null reading even with null value checked

Tags: angular, error-handling, null

My angular code below is throwing errors for can not read (items$ | async) even I tried to check null for it before that. How can I solve this problem?

framework: Angular 14.2.6

```html
<div class="chat-room">
  <!-- <ng-container *ngIf="items$ | async"> -->
  <!-- </ng-container> -->
  <div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async; let i = index">
      <atb-chat-message
        [item]="item"
        [previousSender]="
          (items$ | async) != undefined && i >= 1
            ? (items$ | async)![i - 1].userId
            : undefined
        "
        [nextSender]="
          (items$ | async)!= null && i < (items$ | async)!.length - 1
            ? (items$ | async)![i + 1].userId
            : undefined
        "
      ></atb-chat-message>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
    at ChatRoomComponent_div_1_Template (chat-room.component.html:6:22)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:12084:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11969:13)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:12997:17)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11993:9)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:13043:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11759:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12019:13)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:13043:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11759:9)

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
    at ChatRoomComponent_div_1_Template (chat-room.component.html:6:22)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:12084:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11969:13)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:12997:17)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:11993:9)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:13043:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11759:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:12019:13)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:13043:13)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11759:9)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What kind of `Subject` is `items$`? You're subscribing quite often to the `Observable`. Maybe it would be better to subscribe to `items$` in your controller code and the only access the `items` array from your template code.

Answer (score 0):

The template code is hard to read as you're subscribing quite often to the Observable. Maybe it would be better to subscribe to `items$` only once by either

1. subscribing to the `items$` Observable in the controller code, or
2. assigning the last emitted value of `items$` to a variable in the template code

### Variant 1

**Controller**

```
class Controller implements OnOnit {

  items: SomeType[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // . . .
    items$.subscribe(items => this.items = items || []);
    // . . .
  }
}
```

**Template**

```
<div class="chat-room">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <atb-chat-message
        [item]="item"
        [previousSender]="i >= 1 ? items[i - 1].userId : null"
        [nextSender]="i < items.length - 1 ? items[i + 1].userId : null"
    ></atb-chat-message>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Variant 2

**Template**

```
<div class="chat-room">
  <ng-container *ngIf="(items$ | async) as items">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
      <atb-chat-message
          [item]="item"
          [previousSender]="i >= 1 ? items[i - 1].userId : null"
          [nextSender]="i < items.length - 1 ? items[i + 1].userId : null"
      ></atb-chat-message>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```